# I have an incontinence. Would my urine leakages symptom come and go? or stay forever?

Tags: meaning

got a question about expression come and go.

some dictionary says it come and go away and never come.

other dictionaries say it come and go and come again and go again. repeat

which one is right expression?

Comment: Could you tell us what dictionary or dictionaries give the first definition? In my experience as a native British speaker the second usage is the normal one.

Comment: I've no idea what you're trying to ask.  "Come and go" is an idiom with many different senses, and it is often used it an ironic or jocular sense that you can only understand if you are immersed in the language.  Plus of course it has several literal senses.

Comment: Your title mentions 'urine leakages'. But your question content doesn't. Can you give the full sentence that you want to check? Context matters especially with idioms.

Comment: Some things come and go repeatedly; some things come and go, never to return. It depends on the context. Unless you can provide a context, this question can't be answered in any way other than "both are correct" or "it depends."

Answer (score 1):

When a medical condition lasts for a long time or happens multiple times over a long time, we say it is a *chronic* condition.

When a medical condition only lasts a short time, it's technically an *acute* condition, although this technical meaning is not often used in day-to-day English.

I would imagine that it is possible to experience either chronic or acute incontinence. If you need to understand when or why it could be one or the other, that is a question for a medical or biology Q&A, not an English language issue.

Comment: I agree. I think that the English language question would be better served by people with medical knowledge of what the terms mean to them.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "come and go" or "comes and goes" can refer to symptoms that are intermittent. This means the happen, perhaps suddenly or unexpectantly, and stop just as suddenly.